# Android - How can I make my custom view fill the whole screen?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom view named FloorView. I want this Floor view to be occupying the whole screen, and I need this dynamically (maybe match_parent). I don't want to hard code the size of the view.

I've tried doing this in FloorView.kt

```
    private val rectangle = RectF(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(),
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(), 0f, 0f)
```

I was thinking I could use the match_parent attribute, and match the ConstraintLayout of my MainActivity, but that didn't work, nothing was drawn, possibly because the ConstraintLayout doesn't exist yet

My code for the FloorView.kt is this

```
class FloorView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        color = Color.BLACK
    }
    private val rectangle = RectF(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(),
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(), 0f, 0f)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas!!.drawRect(rectangle, paint)
    }

}
```

How can I make a custom view occupy all available screen space? (like match_parent)

Comment: You should retrieve & use the device's `height` & `width` if you want to fill the whole screen because the constant value of `MATCH_PARENT` is `-1` & you are converting it to a `float` which is not valid.

Comment: How would I do that within my FloorView.kt?

Comment: @DarShan hey brody, it worked. i'd like to give you the correct answer reward, but i don't know how with a comment?

Comment: I just posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```kotlin
class FloorView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val displayMetrics by lazy { Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics }
    private val deviceWidth by lazy { (displayMetrics.widthPixels).toFloat() }
    private val deviceHeight by lazy { (displayMetrics.heightPixels).toFloat() }

    // you can also use this.width & this.Height if this view already
    // added in a ViewGroup via XML
    private val rectangle by lazy { RectF(0f, 0f, deviceWidth, deviceHeight) }

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        color = Color.BLACK
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas!!.drawRect(rectangle, paint)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys meniman98 doesn't want a view of "screen size", just want the view to match parent view's size. Actually "screen size" is impossible -- a view can not exceed its parent ViewGroup's size.

The question is in

```
private val rectangle = RectF(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(),
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toFloat(), 0f, 0f)
```

this will not get expected size because MTACH_PARENT is just a const int to instruct the layout planner, not size.

View's size is first decided in view's onSizeChanged call, so you should override this function and create the rectangle there.

```
private var rectangle:RectF? = null
override fun onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    rectangle = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
}
```